# Error compiling Google Protocol Buffer Output (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17, protocol-buffers

**Update #2: Issue closed, but curious about all the error messages.**

**I got it to compile after including #define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS.  After the build, the Error List still shows 398 errors and the output window lists a lot of warnings, but it still compiled.  Why is that?**

I downloaded the Google Protocol Buffer source and was able to compile it without issues on Visual Studio 2015.  However, the Google Protocol Buffer compiler generates C++ output that has a lot of compile errors.  Is the compiler output below compatible with Visual Studio 2015 (C++14, I think)?  Looks like a later standard of C++.  If it's not, does anyone familiar with Google Protocol Buffer for C++ know how to make it output VS2015-friendly output?  I downloaded from here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

[image]

Update: Here's the compiler output:

1>   Creating library C:\DEV\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DEV\VSSolution\x64\Debug\Monitor.lib and object C:\DEV\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DEV\VSSolution\x64\Debug\Monitor.exp
1>msgcore.pb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class google::protobuf::internal::ExplicitlyConstructed<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >,8> google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string" (?fixed_address_empty_string@internal@protobuf@google@@3V?$ExplicitlyConstructed@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@$07@123@A)
1>C:\DEV\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DEV\VSSolution\x64\Debug\Monitor.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Strange, I see 510 compiler errors under the Error List tab of Visual Studio, but under the compiler output, I only see the one unresolved externals error above.  That's a linking error implying that it already compiled?  How come I don't see the compiler errors high-lighted in the screenshot below and on the Error List in the Output window?

Comment: What sayeth the compiler? Pick one error or a small family of them and add the raw build output from the Output Tab usually found next to the Error List.

Comment: @user4581301 - Thanks, I pasted the compiler output above.

Comment: Those extra errors are likely generated by Intellisense. It's it 's own thing responsible for realtime feedback. Because it needs to report in real-time, it's a lot simpler than an honest-to-gosh compiler in order to be fast. Consider it a compiler that's allowed to be wrong so long as it's fast. In this case it looks to be very, very wrong.

Comment: As for the real linker error... Weird. My MSVC's probably too weak to help you out much. Best I can do, when I get back to my big box, is fire up VS 2015, build up the library, and see where I get stuck.

Comment: I resolved the linker error.  Had to #define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS.

Comment: Pad that out a bit and you've got a good candidate for a self-answer so you can help out future programmers with the same problem. Would you click on a question with no answers if it popped up in a search list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors turned out to be Visual Studio Intellisense errors and not "actual" compile errors.  For the one linking error, the issue was resolved by adding #define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS to the protoc-generated C++ output.